# xypic not showing arrowheads

Tags: xy-pic

I have (supposedly) successfully installed xypic and am attempting to draw some diagrams. Everything is compiling just fine, but no matter what I do I cannot get the heads of the arrows to appear. All that shows up is the base of the arrow. For instance,

```
\begin{xy}
{\ar (0,0)*+{A}; (25,0)*+{A}};
\end{xy}
```

shows no arrow head.

Comment: Are you sure this is not an artifact of your viewer?  What does the arrow look like if you open the PDF in Adobe Reader?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I tried both of these already and it's still not including the arrowheads. I was thinking I might have place some of the files in the wrong directory. For instance, I couldn't come up with a natural place to put the Metafont (.mf) files in my ~/Library/texmf directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you're using a Mac, why did you have to install xypic in the first place? It should be part of your distribution.  Maybe you should remove everything you installed in ~/Library/texmf and try it again. Your sample code works fine for me on a Mac, without having installed anything other than a full MacTeX.

Comment: @Jasper: if would be good if you would post that comment as an answer, additionally.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\usepackage[all,dvips]{xy}` or `\usepackage[all,pdftex]{xy}` in the preamble according to whether you compile the diagram via `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` or `pdflatex`.

Also try updating your packages; sometimes there is a bug in one or two packages that would be fixed after the update.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and the dvips/pdftex fix didn't work for me.
However, I eventually got it working by making sure I included `\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}` in my preamble. Worth a try :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.