# Using \usepackage[all]{xy} and \xymatrix{} the arrowheads are not printing or viewing correctly

Tags: arrows, xy-pic, postscript

When I use `\usepackage[all]{xy}` and `\xymatrix{}` the arrowheads are not printing or viewing correctly. I have typeset for years and this problem only popped up when I changed operating systems a few months ago. If I use ps2pdf on my postscript file, the pdf file views and prints as it should. However I need a good postscript file too. I noticed a posting here about a file being missing from the package. Could that be causing my problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: We had a question about something similar before, could you take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16619/xypic-not-showing-arrowheads/18049#18049 and see if the answer there solves your problem?